# current time falls between given 2 times java

Tags: java

I want to find that current time falls between x and y time ignoring Date component.

My time can fall between next day as well.
I want to know the best way of doing this.

I want to check that my current time falls between below 2 times.
22 PM - 7 AM(Next Day Morning)

I know the way like compare hour part first then minutes but don't know this is best way. I want to know the standard practice people use for this.

Comment: please read properly and then give negative vote... I know solution but dont know the best practice for this.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

Calendar.before() and Calendar.after() methods.
Date.after() and Date.before() methods.

```
    Calendar myTime = ...;
    Calendar startTime = ...;
    Calendar endTime = ...;

    boolean valid = myTime.after(startTime) && myTime.before(endTime);
```

There could be other options as well.